# Fade-in/out animation with a boolean flag

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I am trying to implement a simple "tap to toggle the visibility of the UI" in SwiftUI with fade in/out animation. The following code animates the fade-in effect of the Text element as I expected, but it immediately hides the Text element when *isVisible* become false.

I'd like to understand why this code does not work, and how to fix it in the most natural way.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isVisible = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 1).onEnded {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                        isVisible.toggle()
                    }
                })
            if isVisible {
                Text("Tap me!")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I'm using Xcode 12.5 on Big Sur, and my iPhone is running iOS 14.5.1.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67707814/14351818

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Erik Philips, here is the answer.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isVisible = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .zIndex(1)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 1).onEnded {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                        isVisible.toggle()
                    }
                })
            if isVisible {
                Text("Tap me!")
                    .zIndex(2)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```